# How to install JDOM in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, jdom

I just downloaded the file `jdom-2.0.5.zip` so I can make my apps manipulate xml files, the thing is, I don't know where to place it or how to install it.

Answer (score 1):

You can unzip the "zip" file and move it to the "libs" folder the jar file of your project in Android Studio.

Check if you have in your gradle this code line:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Comment: The libs folder is in your module "app".

Comment: Should I place all the files inside the folder extracted or just the file?.

Comment: But is not only one. there are many, I downloaded the one that says JDOM 2.0.5: http://jdom.org./downloads/index.html... And its not only one jar file.

Comment: Copy and paste all .jars. Or just the file "jdom-2.0.5.jar"

Comment: I just copied the "jdom-2.0.5.jar", I opened Android Studio again.

Comment: In a java file, I have imported this packages: import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.Element;
import org.jdom.JDOMException;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom.output.Format;
import org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter;                                       And Android Studio doesn't recognize the .jdom and mark it as red.

Comment: Well since this can already use this library. Pless check correct answer.